# What is meant by "large" in "binary large object" or Blob

Tags: mysql, sql, blob, binary-data

Since large is kind of a relative term I'd like to know what is exactly meant by "large". More specifically, I want to store binary data ranging from just a couple of bytes up to 50 in my database and was wondering if I should go with a `Blob` or perhaps some other datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no clear definition over all DBMS. But according to MySQL:

- < 256 Byte TINYBLOB
- < 64 KiB BLOB
- < 16 MiB MEDIUMBLOB
- < 4 GiB LONGBLOB

So based on your need, a TINYBLOB would be enough.

Comment: True, and I think they are all stored in a similar fashion, which is outside the record space, in contrast to int or varchar, which consume a part of the max of 65KB for a record. Each of the types will store the length of the data followed by the actual data. The main difference is the size of the length indicator. This is 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes for the forementioned types respectively.

Comment: I cannot say this for MySQL without deeper looking, but on other systems at least the smaller ones are store inline on the page.

Comment: I think that is true for VARBINARY, but not for the various blob types.

Comment: As I mentioned, I cannot say for MySQL. On e.g. ASA I would be configurable during CREATE TABLE ... but this is OT here ;)